# why is specialised template being called?

Tags: c++11, templates

I created a template called `debug` which is indirectly invoked through the function `errorMsg`. I then specialised the template to account for char * (code w/comments below hopefully helps with explanations)

After some playing around I was surprised that even though I defined the template specialisations at a point after they're called in errorMsg(), they were still being used.

I would have assumed because it had not yet been defined at the point the main template would instantiate a default copy or an error would occur

Any help resolving this issue would be great thanks

```
#include  "header.h"
int main()
{

    //std::vector<std::string> s_vec{"abc","cede","rfind"};
    int i = 3;
    int *j = &i;
    errorMsg(std::cout,"hey"); //<---calls debug
}


//defined specialisations after its invoked inside errorMsg
template <>
inline std::string debug(char * p)
{
    std::cout<<"specialsed char"<<std::endl;
    return debug(std::string(p));
}

template <>
inline std::string debug(const char *p)
{
    std::cout<<"specialised const char"<<std::endl;
    return debug(std::string(p));
```

(header.h)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

//(1)
template <typename T>
std::string debug(const T&s)
{   
    std::cout<<"unspecialised obj"<<std::endl;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss<<s;
    return oss.str();
}

//(2)
template <typename T>
std::string debug(T *ptr)
{   
    std::cout<<"unspecialised raw ptr"<<std::endl;
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << "pointer: "<<ptr;
    if (ptr)
    {   
        oss<<" "<<debug(*ptr);
    }
    else
        oss<<" null pointer";

    return oss.str();
}

template <typename T, typename... Args> void print(std::ostream &os,const T &t,const Args&...rest);
template <typename T> std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os, const T &t);


template <typename... Args>
void errorMsg(std::ostream &os,Args &&...args)
{
    print(os,debug(std::forward<Args>(args))...); //debug called here
}

template <typename T>
std::ostream &print(std::ostream &os, const T &t)
{
    return os<<t<<std::endl;
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
void print(std::ostream &os,const T &t,const Args&...rest)

{
    os<<t<<", ";
    print(os,rest...);
}
```

result:

```
specialised const char
unspecialised obj
hey
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **[temp.expl.spec]/6** If a template, a member template or a member of a class template is explicitly specialized then that specialization shall be declared before the first use of that specialization that would cause an implicit instantiation to take place, in every translation unit in which such a use occurs; no diagnostic is required.

Your program is ill-formed; no diagnostic required.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I just had a look at the meaning of ill-formed no diagnostic required. Just to clarify, so my program is exhibiting undefined behaviour as it is allowed to compile but doesn't follow **[temp.expl.spec]/6**. This specification outlines a scenario where compilation could fail but doesnt as a result of lack of implementation

Comment: Well, technically, ill-formed;NDR is not the same thing as undefined behavior, but it's a distinction without a difference. Don't do it, and if you do, anything can happen, including "seems to work".